# Different versions of librosa.load lead to different result

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I tested this on two versions of librosa 0.8.1 and 0.6.3, and the results are as follows
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EwTV.png)
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mq8T.png)

I want to know why, and how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. In librosa doc, they changed the audio decoder to pyaudio in newer versions, instead of soundfile